# ¿Como se la posición de un numero aleatorio?

Tags: c#, programacion-asincrona

me dejaron este ejercicio en clase, pero realmente no se como resolverlo.

**1.Se tiene una serie de n números enteros, se quiere saber si dentro de esta serie, existe, por lo menos, uno cuyo valor sea cero, de cumplirse la condición muestre, cuántos valores previos a cero hay en dicha serie**

Por ahora llevo el código así:

```
using System;

using System.ComponentModel.Design;

using System.Numerics;

public class Ejercicio_7_2
{ 
    public static void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("ingrese la cantidad de numeros que desea: ");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
        Random generador = new Random();
        int [] num = new int [n];
        for (int i=0;i<=n;i++)
        {

            num[i] = generador.Next(0,10);
            Console.WriteLine("numero aleatorio: " + num[i]);
        
        }
    }
}
```

Pero no se como mostrar cuantos valores previos a 0 hay en la serie, ¿alguna solucion?.

Comment: Saludos. Declara una variable que sea tu contados; inicialízalo en cero; luego del Console que tiene evalua si n[i] es igual a cero e incrementa tu contador. fuera del for imprimes el valor del contador.

Comment: Por qué está la etiqueta de programación asíncrona? Ese ejercicio lo requiere?

Answer (score 2):

La cantidad de números previos coincide con la posición del elemento. Así que puedes usar la función [`Array.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-8.0) para obtener la posición del primer **0**. Si no hay ninguno devuelve **-1**.

```
Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cantidad de numeros que desea: ");
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
Random generador = new Random();
int [] serie = new int [n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    serie[i] = generador.Next(0,10);
    Console.WriteLine("Numero aleatorio: " + serie[i]);
}

var previos = Array.IndexOf(serie, 0);
if (previos == -1) 
   Console.WriteLine("La serie no tiene 0");
else
   Console.WriteLine($"Hay {previos} valores previos");
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##fVI9b8IwEN3zK55Qh0RAFIYupQxVlyJRiujQoWI4JUdkKbHbs6EglN@emnypS8nylPP7uDs7tdPUCNf1wSqd4/1sHZfzIC3IWmzE5EIlLgEA68ipFEejMryS0qF14iWfO5DkNmpJwLPR1hQcf4hyvFKaw9FS58KWURBS0k5llCFj6EPJYiy@D@x/LdMDRtG8dVHaQWNxxXhDYjnsfbdMWWMbRXO05C3pzJTIWbNQZsTrNP905fCvpW/WsijuGE1J7zrC3ivDa0n542Tu4RHaw3gctYRuwuvXuHyqnWcOsfGaTy5MJrOkj/xnH@tmcFDB5Iwo4@fGeLDsxVXQ4pEEX8JH5Ve1wJMIneOlzvj0tg8bzQRDoNojHLgLTGcRghuNrKhbhzZwys@BZLgBLizf0N6NXuiMSxdW@S4L/4xs32lnUwVVXd//Ag).

---

Si no tienes que conservar los números previos, no necesitas ningún arreglo. Aunque tendrías que implementar algo similar a la función `Array.IndexOf`.

`i` coincide con la posición y a su vez con la cantidad de números previos. Así que hay que guardarla cuando encuentre un **0**.

Es necesario darle un valor inicial a esa variable que permita distinguir si se encontró o no. Por qué no, usemos **-1** como la función.

```
Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cantidad de numeros que desea: ");
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
Random generador = new Random();
int previos = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    int nAleatorio = generador.Next(0,10);
    Console.WriteLine("Numero aleatorio: " + nAleatorio);

    // Sin la segunda condición, la variable se actualizaría con cada 0 que encuentre.
    if (nAleatorio == 0 && previos == -1){
        previos = i;
        // Si no te interesan los números posteriores a 0, puedes quitar la segunda
        // condición y agregar un break aquí para que el ciclo termine antes.
    }
}

if (previos == -1) 
   Console.WriteLine("La serie no tiene 0");
else
   Console.WriteLine($"Hay {previos} valores previos");
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##fVJNT8JAEL33V7wQQ9ogpBy8iByMF02QEDx4MB4m7dBsUnZ1Z0EJ6W/HAVtbEsNeJjs772t3MxlmzvPhsBFjC7zsJPB6EmUliWDhXeFpjX0EQAIFk2HrTI5nMjaW4BXy9g7yhSS/Q7oenBVX8ujVm8AzYznuPdnCszBKQkY2mJxy5Ay7WbN3gs8N61aYbtFLJjWNsQEW02MdLcgLxw3xkik/8SbJBPX0kmzu1ijYsqfceQVa/qrb8Rnph@etUdUphuOmv1JEfDw02k4nWu5gtQwGST3RpGuc3ZdMwXnjFPCnOprzd4jT63H6p/j/hcxPyUENiQbHoEOq8I7eCnFXTx2i329zHIMkHX@62oymY6SKmhq1zOc0uGh7RhD2Rl/OIRhNjbR9MC6FL6Gveo@0w77Wq7ClUj@eNF5roiqqDoebHw).

Answer (score -3):

```
numeros = [2, 5, 0, 8, -3, 7, 0, 1]

encontrado = False
previos = 0

for i in range(len(numeros)):
    
    if numeros[i] == 0:
        encontrado = True
        break
    else:
        previos += 1

 if:
     print("Se encontró un cero")
     print("La cantidad de valores previos a cero es:", previos)
 else:
     print("No se encontró ningún cero")
```

Comment: Bienvenido. La pregunta es en C# no python.

Comment: int[] numeros = { 2, 5, 0, 8, -3, 7, 0, 1 };
bool encontrado = false;
int previos = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < numeros.Length; i++)
{
    if (numeros[i] == 0)
    {
        encontrado = true;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        previos++;
    }
}

if (encontrado)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Se encontró un cero");
    Console.WriteLine("La cantidad de valores previos a cero es: " + previos);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No se encontró ningún cero");
}

Comment: Hola Ernesto, bienvenido, podrías editar tu pregunta con las correcciones que agregas como comentario?, así evitarás recibir votos negativos, por otro lado, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, podrías explicar como tu código resuelve el problema?, gracias.